# What is the difference between Trax and Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, data-science-model

What is the main difference between Trax and Tensorflow?

Both of them are deep learning libraries and implemented by Google.

https://github.com/google/trax

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow

Comment: They aren't necessarily competing; it looks more like they are complementary. You can [work with both of them together](https://trax-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/tf_numpy_and_keras.html). I don't know why they maintain two different libraries though, my guess is that they originated from opensourcing different projects by different google research teams.

Comment: Related thread at Stack Overflow: [What is the difference between JAX, Trax, and TensorRT, in simple terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60766116/what-is-the-difference-between-jax-trax-and-tensorrt-in-simple-terms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trax is a high-level interface to make it easy to apply existing models (like ResNet, LSTM, Transformer). Trax focuses almost exclusively on deep learning.

TensorFlow is a data flow computational framework that can be applied to a wide variety of problems. TensorFlow allows fine grain control over every step in the modeling process. TensorFlow is often used for deep learning, but given its flexibility it can be used for any numerical computation.